# Alocação dinâmica em C++

Tags: c++, memória, alocação

Estava aprendendo um pouco mais sobre alocação dinâmica em C++ na internet, e um código de um professor me chamou a atenção.

É um código feito pra gastar apenas o necessário de memória e não ter "espaço em branco", armazenando apenas a quantidade de caracteres utilizada.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char *nome;
    nome = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)+1);

    gets(nome);

    cout << nome << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Pelo que eu saiba, a alocação de memória em C++ é feita através do `new`, não utilizando `malloc()`.

Outra coisa que me chamou a atenção foi que esse código não estaria invadindo memória já que foi alocada apenas um espaço de 2 bytes?

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida sobre alocação de memória em c/c++,o operador new é sim do c++,é mais abstrato que o malloc um vez que não precisa especificar o tamanho em bytes da sua alocação dinâmica

Comment: Minha dúvida é se esse código está invadindo memória, já que só foi alocado 2 bytes para a variável "nome" e se esse código é a maneira correta de se alocar memória em C++, já que aparenta ser um código de C, tirando o "cout".

Comment: Alocação em c++ é feita com `new`, mas ninguem lhe impede de utilizar `malloc`, embora não deva. Ja que falo nos "não deva", também não deve usar `gets` em c++ que foi marcado como obsoleto no c++11 e removido no c++14. Mas qual é a sua questão especificamente ?

Comment: Bom, esse código teoricamente é feito para utilizar apenas a quantidade de memória necessária, por exemplo, o usuário digitou uma string com 15 caracteres, ela ira consumir apenas os dados necessário para armazenar 15 caracteres + o finalizador de string. Porém, creio que só esteja alocando um espaço de 2 bytes, ou seja, 1 caractere + o finalizador de string. De fato esse código está invadindo memória? Ou está cumprindo com sua proposta sem invadir memória?

Comment: Você alocou 2 bytes, se guardar mais de 2 bytes está a invadir memoria. Conclusão: qualquer coisa que o usuário coloque com mais de uma letra (a outra é para o terminador) representa acesso invalido na memoria, no caso buffer overflow e consequente comportamento indefinido.

Comment: Muito obrigado, então de fato é oq eu pensava, está invadindo memória. Pelo visto vou ter que mudar minha fonte de estudo, alguma sugestão?

Comment: A [wiki da tag c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) já tem uma sugestão de livros bons no tópico. Bons estudos.

Comment: Cada programa executado na RAM tem um espaço próprio para sua execução,sendo que este espaço é divido por algumas áreas,sendo as principais a stack,onde será feita uma pilha,e a heap,onde são as variáveis alocadas dinamicamente, esse espaço de 2 bytes está sendo alocado no espaço destinado a ele,o que poderia acontecer,é o uso da heap total do programa,porém , há uma alocação de mais espaço, quanto ao código é o malloc mesmo,bem baixo nível,outra coisa,não esquecer de usar o free,para liberar esse memória alocada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estava aprendendo alocar memória assim na internet, saia correndo. Quase todo o conteúdo existente na internet sobre programação é ruim, alguma coisa salva e para um leigo é muito difícil identificar o que é ruim porque ele não sabe ainda, então é melhor procurar só fontes que sejam reconhecidamente confiáveis.

Neste caso sua preocupação não deve ser essa, este código deveria ser só assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nome;
    cin >> nome;
    cout << nome << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GPbOGf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SimpleString). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/SimpleString.cpp).

De fato, se fosse fazer uma alocação deveria usar [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) e não `malloc()`, e mesmo assim só em código muito específico, provavelmente uma biblioteca, em código normal isso é mais raro, o mais comum é o tipo fazer seu próprio gerenciamento de memória ou usar *smart pointers*.

Se fosse usar o `malloc()` deveria usar logo 2, não tem porque usar `sizeof(char)` porque ele sempre é 1.

Este código tem erros demais e deve ser completamente ignorado, inclusive ele aloca espaço para apenas 1 caractere e vai corromper a memória.